# nested Sqlite Query not working properly

Tags: html, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

In this code outer sqlite query first finish its work then it goes to inner sqlite query
 Please explain me why it happen and also give the solution of my requirment.

```
/*Outer Sqlite Query*/
 db.transaction(function(transaction){
 transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM OuterTable;', [], 
 function(transaction,results){
   if (results != null && results.rows != null) { 
     for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
      /*My work is going here*/             

       /*Inner Sqlite Query   Inside lor loop*/
       db.transaction(function(transaction){        
   transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM MyInnerTable;',[],
   function(transaction, result){
   if (result != null && result.rows != null)  {                                   
         for (var j = 0; j < result.rows.length; j++) {
              /* My Work is Going here */
           }
            }
     },errorHandler);
     } ,errorHandler,nullHandler);
       /*Inner Sqlite End Here*/                 
                        }
                      }
                   },errorHandler);
                  }
                  ,errorHandler,nullHandler);
           /*Outer Sqlite End Here*/
```

The Problem is That here
  First---> Outer Sqlite Work is Executing then Inner Sqlite work is executing but my Requirment is as like
 for each value of Outer Sqlite Inner Sqlite will be work

for Example:--

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<=10;j++){
   // here inner for loop will work for every value of outer for loop

   }
 }
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: keep in mind that those calls are asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement to perform the inner query for every outer query cannot be achieved like this. Since the SELECT queries are async calls.

Even the outer for loop doesn't wait for your the query at previous index to be completed. It will continue execution and simultaneously fire SELECT queries.

However, to achieve that you can use recursion.

Where each outer loop calls the select query, the success callback implements the inner query and the success callback of the inner query recursively calls the inner query for the required number of times with the required index and post the number of times (inner loop for condition) it would call the outer query implementer with an incremented index.

Hope that helps.